# Why, when I run this code, does the button not span the whole width of the dialog

Tags: python, tkinter

The code: http://pastebin.com/nXqFT7wz

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox


def mbox(title, text):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title, text)


def calculate():
    num1 = num_1.get()
    num2 = num_2.get()
    total = int(num1) + int(num2)
    mbox("Your total is: ", total)

root = tk.Tk()

label_1 = tk.Label(root, text="First Number")
label_2 = tk.Label(root, text="Second Number")
num_1 = tk.Entry(root)
num_2 = tk.Entry(root)
button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="Login", command=calculate)

label_1.grid(row=0)
label_2.grid(row=1)

num_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
num_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_1.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

root.geometry("218x70")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Adder")

root.mainloop()
```

Why, when I run this, is the button not the width of the two columns that are used in the window? Theoretically, the button should be the width of the label and the entry (which is two columns), but it just appears centered in the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stick` to resize widget

```
button_1.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, stick="WE")
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `xticky` option, to tell the widget to "stick" to the sides of the space allocated to it. If you want it to fill all the way to the left and right use `"ew"` (east/west):

```
button_1.grid(..., sticky="ew")
```